# jQuery to target CSS a:hover class

Tags: jquery, css, class, hover

Confused here. What's the best way to change the hover CSS of the link below, and how? toggle.Class? add.Class? I want to show an image on hover. I have been able to change the color of the text with

```
$("#menu-item-1099 a:contains('rss')").css("color", "#5d5d5d");
```

but can't seem to target the hover class.

```
<div id="access">
<div class="menu-header">
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-1099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-1099">
<a href="http://mydomain.com/feed/">rss</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `.css()` in jQuery, you're not actually changing the CSS file / creating new CSS rules. You're simply adding CSS to specific elements' `style` attribute (inline CSS).

So, you can't "target the hover class" - you have to do something on hover in, and revert that on hover out:

```
$("#menu-item-1099 a:contains('rss')").hover(function() {
    // Hover in, show an img
    $(this).after("<img src='blah.jpg'>");
    // Or alternatively
    $(this).addClass("hasImage"); // Where there is a CSS rule for .hasImage
}, function () {
    // Hover out, remove the img
    $(this).next().remove();
    // Or alternatively
    $(this).removeClass("hasImage");
});
```

Comment: +1 . Bax9 code is good than my code. because it adds image but my code will add simple color

Comment: Interesting. Maybe there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do? To actually change the css rather than add to it? I.e., how to change the color of the text "rss" in the link? I can't get the code above to work. I'm dealing with a dynamically generated menu, and that may not matter with running the JS with document ready.

Comment: @songdogtech, I'm not sure what you mean by "change the css". If you're talking about changing the CSS file, then yes, that can be done, but it's not recommended. My above code may not work if your menu is dynamically generated, you will need to use `.live` instead. But if all you're after is a highlighted link, why can't you give a class to all the generated `<a>`, and reference that class directly in your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('a:contains('rss')').live('mouseover mouseout', function (event) {
                if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
                    $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFF99');
                } else {
                    $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
                }
            });
```

it is simple way to make it. when mouseover you can show your image, whne mouseout you can remove your image

Answer (score 0):

You can use .hover on the element, like this

```
  $("#menu-item-1099 a:contains('rss')").hover(function(){
      //change the bacjgound picture
           $(this).addClass("all the class");
        }, function(){

                    //remove it
           $(this).removeClass("all the class");
            });
```

if you want to use .toggle()

```
$("#menu-item-1099 a:contains('rss')").hover(function(){
          $(this).toggleClass(list the class);
                });
```

you only need to create a class on your style sheet, make the background the image you want, and put it here